# "mark the bar" or "clear the bar"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Think of this sentence:

*According to critics, the theory does not mark the bar as a theory*

I am trying to say: it barely comes close to what can be called a theory. I thought "clear the bar" connotes something capable of raising up over the challenge whereas "mark the bar" could indicate that it can not even reach there.

So, does this sentence seem a bit off to the reader or it can be understood in this context.

Comment: You can make the point of abject failure by adding *not even begin*. "According to critics, the [proposition?] does *not even begin* to clear the bar as a theory. Or you could use *falls short*.

Answer (score 2):

The *bar* in expressions like *set the bar*, *raise* or *lower the bar*, or *clear the bar* is borrowed from sports. Specifically, it refers to the physical bar, laid horizontally, which measures achievement in events like the high jump and pole vault, in what is called *athletics* in British English and *track and field* in American English. The OED attests to this usage since at least 1869, and the metaphorical expression from the mid-20th century.

In such events, a competitor must jump, hurtle, etc. over the bar in order to qualify for the next round of competition.

[image: High jump at the men's athletics at the Sports Ground, 1935, by Sam Hood (Wikimedia Commons)]

To *clear the bar* is thus to attain the required standard. The bar can be set low initially, allowing many competitors to advance, or high, eliminating many competitors early on. Raising the bar represents a tightening of standards, and a performance that far exceeds the bar would cause officials to adjust it upwards, and thus is also said to raise the bar.

To *mark the bar* makes no sense in this analogy. Those who fail to meet the standard knock the bar to the ground; they do not mark it. Once they miss the bar, they are eliminated from the competition. You should choose a different metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the existing answers are correct in that your metaphor is inappropriate.

To "clear the bar" does not mean being *capable* of meeting or exceeding some criterion, but simply of *actually* meeting or exceeding it.

However, you have a bigger problem. Even *if* your metaphor worked, your sentence wouldn't make sense. To paraphrase it:

> Your theory does not meet the standards of a theory.

But either something *is* a theory or it *isn't*. You can say that a theory is a *poor* theory, but you can't talk about it as a theory (of any quality) and then deny it being one.

So, in order to both fix the metaphor and address this other issue, I can see a few possible ways of rephrasing your sentence:

> According to critics, *your supposition* doesn't even *meet the standards* of a *poor* theory.
>   According to critics, *your supposition* doesn't even *clear the bar* of being a theory.
>   According to critics, *your theory* doesn't *pass the mark* of being a *good* theory.

Answer (score 0):

If 'clear the bar' is a metaphor, where does the imagery come from?

A high-jumper 'clears the bar' when there's a perfect jump that doesn't even shake the bar.
An innkeeper 'clears the bar' when it's time to go home.

'To mark the bar' creates a mixed metaphor (and there's a beery subtext). Better to change the metaphor to something athletic or sporty like '[getting off the mark](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwinm6yPy9jgAhXxQxUIHXEJBWIQFjABegQIChAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fidioms.thefreedictionary.com%2Fget%2Boff%2Bthe%2Bmark&usg=AOvVaw3J9q5ro7jmQuqWOmS1Moqb);' or 'making the start,' which is a very old-fashioned (c1920) expression for 'qualifying for a competition,' 'arriving at the starting blocks.'

Comment: "making the start" is not an idiom in English. The idiom you linked to is "be off the starting blocks".